# format specifier and reversing a 32 bit signed integer

Tags: c

I was given a code in an interview to write a function to reverse a **32** bit signed integer and I wrote this in the third attempt (worked with all test cases):

```
int fun(int x)
{
    char a[11]="";  //this will contain character form of absolute value of number 'x' 
    char b[11]="";  //this will contain reverse of absolute of number 'x'
    char e[11]="";

    short sign = -1;
    short index_a=0;
    short index_b=0;
    short index_e=0;
    short temp_index=0;

    if(x<0)
    {
        sprintf(a,"%u",(unsigned int)(-1*(long int)(x)));
        sprintf(e,"%u",(unsigned int)(-1*(long int)(pow(2,31)))); //setting the limits
        sign = -1;
    }
    else if(x>0)
    {
        sprintf(a,"%u",(unsigned int)x);
        sprintf(e,"%u",(unsigned int)(-1*(long int)(pow(2,31) - 1))); //setting the limits
        sign = 1;
    }
    else
      x=0;

    index_a = strlen(a);
    --index_a;

    //'b' will contain the reversed digits of array 'a'

    while(index_a>=0) //storing it in 'b' from a character by character in reverse order
    {
        b[index_b++] = a[index_a--];
    }

    //here index_a is equal to -1 and index_b is euqal to 'strlen(b)'


    if(index_b==10) //10 is the number of digits in (2^31 - 1) or (2^31)
    {
        while(temp_index<index_b)
        {
           if(b[temp_index]>e[index_e])
                return 0;
           else if(b[temp_index] < e[index_e])
                break;
           temp_index++;
           index_e++;
        }
    }

    return sign*atoi(b);
}
```

I was asked to improve but I couldn't (later came to know that this question was for filtering - I failed I guess) - could you please suggest any other method for this doing this?

The main issue I faced was when the variable **x** was equal to **-(2^31)**, that is why I couldn't simply write `x = abs(x)` - could you also suggest me some links where I can read in deep about signed unsigned limits and format specifiers (**%l** didn't work with `sprintf` hence `%u` was used).

**CONSTRAINTS** -

- In case of overflow/underflow **0** is to be returned.
- The return type is fixed as **int**
- The no. of arguments is fixed.

Comment: if I see something like this `pow(2,31)` I know that I should not employ this guy.

Comment: @P__J__ Sorry I didn't remember the value,could you please suggest me some other method and answer this question? Please!!!

Comment: So much code for a simple request.  Treat as unsigned, for loop all sizeof(int) bits, grab low bit with & and | into new var.  Shift input and new var in opposite directions til done.  There is also a couple of magic number xors you can use to reverse faster, or use intrinsic rev instruction if it exists.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Can you please write that in an answer as I am not getting clearly what you are saying?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus it for sure the worst code I have ever seen (except people who just started learning programming)

Comment: You could have used INT32_MAX and INT32_MIN. You could have avoided using 3 string buffers and use only 1, you could reverse the string by iterating to half the string, replacing characters from the front with the back. More importantly, you could add documentation and comments explaining what the corner cases are.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: The problem is not to reverse the bits. It is to produce the number represented by reversing the decimal digits.

Comment: regarding: `index_a = strlen(a);`   The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `short int`.  When compiling, enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to perform the same functionality

Comment: @user3629249: Assigning to a `short int` is fine because the string length is provably within bounds of a `short int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil,  assigning a unsigned value to a signed value is fraught with perl.

Comment: suggest the OP learn about the function: `abs()` with syntax: `int abs(int j);`

Comment: @user3629249 Would it work in case of  **2^31** as the positive values can lie below or equal to **2^31 - 1**?

Comment: Not all signed 32 bit integers result as a signed 32 bit integer when they are reversed. For example, 2147483647 is 7463847412 which needs 34 bits if stored as a signed integer. Hence, the given code won't work in all cases.

Comment: So if forced to return an int, there is possible overflow and you need to handle this...

Comment: `(long int)(x)` is dubiuous.  `long` may nly be as wide as `int` and serves no wideneing here.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix It works with this overflow condition you have mentioned i.e. **2147483647**  because the constraint says to return 0 in this case else you are right, it can't be contained in a 32 bit field.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan There is constraint for that, sorry I mentioned in the question a bit late.

Comment: Alternative to `sprintf(a,"%u",(unsigned int)(-1*(long int)(x)));` --> `sprintf(a,"%u",0u - x);` or `sprintf(a,"%lld", 0LL - x);`

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus `32bit` integer or `int`. `Int` does not have to be 32bit

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reverse it as a decimal number:

three versions

```
int reverse10(int val)
{
    long long result = 0 ;

    while(val)
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += val % 10;
        val /= 10;
    }
    if(result < INT_MIN || result > INT_MAX) return 0;
    return result;
}

int rev(int32_t val, int32_t *result)
{
    int32_t temp;
    int digit;
    *result = 0;

    while(val)
    {
        temp = *result;
        *result *= 10;
        if(temp != (*result / 10)) {*result = 0; return -1;}
        temp = *result;
        digit = val % 10;
        *result += digit;
        if(temp != (*result - digit)) {*result = 0; return -1;}
        val /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}

int rev1(int val)
{
    int temp;
    int digit;
    int result = 0;

    while(val)
    {
        temp = result;
        result *= 10;
        if(temp != (result / 10)) return 0;
        temp = *result;
        digit = val % 10;
        result += digit;
        if(temp != (result - digit)) return 0;
        val /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It is evident from the code supplied that the problem has requirements for handling overflow, and this answer does not satisfy that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil actually no. I ask similar question to see if interviewee understands the problem. Interview question have to be quite simple - but showing something as people are usually very stressed and it has to be taken into the account

Comment: return type is fixed - **int**

Comment: Still, mod div 10 is how I would approach as well.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus Requirements like "return type is fixed - int " belong in the question - not scattered about in comments.  Also add to question what should happen on overflow.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus I see nothing wrong here- UV.  If code must return an `int`, test result  in the end of the fucniton for being in range [INT_MIN...INT_MAX] and handle out of range answers as desired.

Comment: @EricPostpischil extremelly complicated change

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus it does not change anything. Here you have version which lets know the caller if the overflow happened. If you do not care just change the type of the first function